# Java list ALL files in jar file / How is getResource() working

Tags: java, jar, resources

So my question is: how can i list every file/folder that is in my jar file. Normally i use `Files.walk(myPath)` for this and then i can "walk" through all files e.g. in the folder "/res".

But when i want to walk through the complete jar file i get nothing. For the Path i use "" (<- empty String) because its the "root path".
Even when i check if this path exists, it says yes when i execute the code in my IDE, but when i export it to a jar it can't find the empty path. What am i doing wrong here?

I checked some more Paths e.g. "/", "..", "/..", "../" and i only got null as a resource...

(Checking for existance is done via `getResource(myPath)` and then just null-checking, i've tried the `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` and the ClassLoader from the Class i'm working in (`Test.class.getResource(myPath)` and `Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource(myPath)`), nothing works...)

Comment: What about using java.util.jar.*?

Comment: Oh yes... Thank you, i was so desperate that i've not seen this solution...